# Soft body Point of Contact in Three.js Physijs

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

I have a soft body and a rigid body in a physijs scene. Unfortunately the documentation is slim, and I know bullet physics on which ammo.js/physijs is based has this capability.

When I move the rigid body how can I determine the point(s) of contact on the softbody?

This is so I can deform the soft body in that area by applying velocities to the contacted points.

Comment: I´ve got a solution working with standard ```ammo.js``` rigid bodys and would like to test it before posting. Could you share your code how you are handling soft bodys?

Comment: I'm using a mass spring system inspired by code found in this example: http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/reactive-ball/  My code is virtually the same, the only difference is I'm drawing each spring between the vertices of an imported STL object